# Why does the link in this notification of a new comment not find any new comment?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, email

This notification

[image]

seems to be informing me of a new comment, so given that it has no link on the word *comment* or the speech bubble, I assume the link on the question title is supposed to be a link to the new comment.

But the [URL](http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?upn=pDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnShAxHg-2BF-2FzJSx68B3MkgoJrsu2lfez3BJHTG3E6vB-2BRLhb4fOQHyRYK-2BQodwK76tEXiXkUxl6CbOntYuyEUAWc-3D_bsYyecqj7-2BQAgvd22kJsT6XRk3NeW8Im79dJMBOMY-2BDPnSnaRRMdxgaPz-2FwDjv8nQP9rJO2CQH6zXDumNcYosUbMitC6egOPNn4hbOSUntl6et9NWUVj986pg-2FPDaZlGg7iW7l2QoHGJkuM1K5mKcGxFJ-2BJ1ReLlYz2hsCmAiPdbBPEtMl8RhW2vB4EplUc5rDxdaWkmAldH9TR1gfG0au2KLdK7kQfdk-2FpqEldwuVWaTGwmEk2Znbj-2BvZAOI6k2iIMC-2FTe7pAdhQ-2FLsHvUxl7-2FV5f12QO5jghCxMtD-2B7bxD4jpvdI-2BB5tl2Y5j4t2H-2F8BoQbibMTGv-2FB3t0NQe7QbIzsaSaYYTwywaeSbNZCJKSzqjTb1JmCz3PT1xrgDHmKKpiO8bh5Ft0Fh-2Fzy0nueTJMt7UKswhchUSsLnxugWUHAVr6NMcEsN1J2NQohdy3qDmquumLWVjaMktiWNXHe4hbP1jvDVrHh5LMamd4a2E9Vbwwf6YBmTsJOtuemMz9) of that link fails to show a comment. It briefly shows

[image]

and then scrolls to

[image]

Manually scanning the comments for the date-time cited in the notification (Oct 20 at 7:29) finds none.

Comment: My guess: the comment was probably deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The comment was automatically generated because someone voted to close as a duplicate.

Then, the comment was automatically deleted because the question got closed as a duplicate of that question.

As the comment was deleted, links to it redirect to the parent post.

As for the email notifying about a deleted comment being sent, it might take a little while for unread notifications resulting from since-deleted comments to get removed from the notification bar due to caching and batch-processing. It's likely that the script that generates the email ran before the notification was cleared, and it saw an unread notification and thus sent the email.

Comment: Someone didn't think that through, then.

Comment: @ChrisJJ It might take a little while for unread notifications resulting from since-deleted comments to get removed from the notification bar due to caching and batch-processing, and it's likely that the script that generates the email ran before the notification was cleared, and it saw an unread notification and sent the email.